# Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found during web application build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

When I develop a web application via Visual Studio 2013 (version 12.0.21005) and compile/build and run locally (Citrix Desktop) it works fine. However, when the same project is built in our BUILD server it fails with the following error.

"error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found."

Looking at the build server (under C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio folder) I can find that there are v10.0 and v14.0 installed.

What instructs the system to look for v11.0 when other versions are avaiable on the server. is there some setting on the csproj or the solution file (as my WindowsForms based projects compile fine in the BUILD server)

Unfortunately I do not have the rights to install MSBUID in either the Citrix Desktop or the Build Server

Logged into the servers to find the available build versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the following post.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/visual-studio-project-compatibility-and-visualstudioversion/

Als refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild for version history